# Insert a Static DataTable in Primefaces

Tags: html, jsf, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

My question is the following: how can I insert a DataTable with static rows and static columns?
These columns and rows will always have the same value.

I have the following table with all the rows and columns with static data but this does not work for me:

```
<div class="card">
  <p:dataTable lazy="false">

    <p:column headerText="Color">
        <h:outputText value="Red" />
        <h:outputText value="Yellow" />
        <h:outputText value="Green" />
        <h:outputText value="Orange" />
    </p:column>
        
    <p:column headerText="Test">
        <h:outputText value="Test11111" />
        <h:outputText value="Test22222" />
        <h:outputText value="Test33333" />
        <h:outputText value="Test44444" />
    </p:column>
        
</p:dataTable>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: We dont support something via markup only. But you can create something like a static (AppScoped) bean and get the data from there.

Comment: Why not use https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/panelGrid.xhtml

Answer (score 0):

Just use a panelGrid.

```
<p:panelGrid columns="4">
            <h:outputText value="Red" />
            <h:outputText value="Yellow" />
            <h:outputText value="Green" />
            <h:outputText value="Orange" />
            <h:outputText value="Test11111" />
            <h:outputText value="Test22222" />
            <h:outputText value="Test33333" />
            <h:outputText value="Test44444" />
</p:panelGrid>
```